# Modify url via ajax, problem with window.history.pushState()

Tags: jquery, ajax, page-refresh

I play around with AJAX-calls on my local server to try different things.

One is, as you can guess, modifying the url without page refresh.

So far I have following.

```
$('.links').click(function (e) {
    
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    
    e.preventDefault();

    //window.history.pushState("","",targetUrl);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/3113/public/ajax/index",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data){
            //alert('test');
            $('#showmystuff').html('<b>'+data+'</b>');
            
        },
        error:function (){
            alert('Something went wrong');
        },
    });
    
});
```

and in my body I have a div-Container like

```
<div id="showmystuff"></div>
```

and everything works fine.

But when I comment out window.history.pushState it doesnt work. The data is not loaded in the div-container.

Can someone explain me why? I´ve read a couple of related topics but I have no idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens instead? Is the request made at all? Do you see it in your dev-tools _Network_ panel? Do you have any errors reported in your console?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/4dvhLwos/

Comment: Oh thanks for the hint with the console. Yes, there is indeed a message.
It says:

Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure. welcome:481
    <anonym> https://localhost/3113/public/welcome/:481
    dispatch http://localhost/3113/public/vendors/scripts/core.js:3
    handle http://localhost/3113/public/vendors/scripts/core.js:3

Comment: The line 481 is

e.preventDefault();

in my code above.

Comment: I think that's unlikely. Since you appear to be making a request to the same host, avoid using fully qualified URLs. Try `url: "/3113/public/ajax/index"` or some other relative URL. Right now it looks like you're trying to request an `http://` URL from an `https://` page

Comment: Oh my gosh.... yeah that´s the point. I do not know why I worked with 
h t t p s : / / localhost

I have no idea. Everything works fine now. Sorry for wasting your time. :D

I appreciate your help and also the fiddle. Thanks for all.